# Dynamically setting a 'targetSize' for centerCropWindow2d()

Tags: matlab, crop

Following the example from the [documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/centercropwindow2d.html?searchHighlight=crop%20window&s_tid=srchtitle) of the centerCropWindow2d function, I am trying to dynamically crop an image based on a 'scale' value that is set by the user. In the end, this code would be used in a loop that would scale an image at different increments, and compare the landmarks between them using feature detection and extraction methods.

I wrote some test code to try and isolate 1 instance of this user-specified image cropping,

```
file = 'frameCropped000001.png';
image = imread(file);

scale = 1.5;
scaled_width = scale * 900;
scaled_height = scale * 635;
target_size = [scaled_width scaled_height];

scale_window = centerCropWindow2d(size(image), target_size);
image2 = imcrop(image, scale_window);

figure;
imshow(image);

figure;
imshow(image2);
```

but I am met with this error:

```
Error using centerCropWindow2d (line 30)
Expected input to be integer-valued.

Error in testRIA (line 20)
scale_window = centerCropWindow2d(size(image), target_size);
```

Is there no way to do use this function the way I explained above? If not, what's the easiest way to "scale" an image without just resizing it [that is, if I scale it by 0.5, the image stays the same size but is zoomed in by 2x].

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't take into account that the height and width for some scales would NOT be whole integers. Since Matlab cannot crop images that are inbetween whole pixel numbers, the "Expected input to be integer-valued." popped up.

I solved my issue by using Math.floor() on the 'scaled_width' and 'scaled_height' variables.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).